# Jquery loop through table find highest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Question:

I have a  HTML box  where I can input a value then 10% is added to each side to create a range. If a row's columns value doesn't fall in the range it is hidden. I want to find the highest unhidden value and assign it's value to `bestrange`. I then want to check all hidden rows under `bestrangeprice`'s price and see if they have a higher score then `bestrangemark`'s score and if so show them.

I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶g̶o̶t̶t̶e̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ ̶p̶a̶r̶t̶ ̶u̶n̶t̶i̶l̶ ̶a̶s̶s̶i̶g̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶`̶b̶e̶s̶t̶r̶a̶n̶g̶e̶`̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶m̶o̶s̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶c̶h̶e̶c̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶a̶n̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶h̶i̶g̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶`̶b̶e̶s̶t̶r̶a̶n̶g̶e̶`̶.̶ ̶I̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶a̶s̶s̶i̶g̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶`̶b̶e̶s̶t̶r̶a̶n̶g̶e̶`̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶a̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶u̶n̶h̶i̶d̶d̶e̶n̶ ̶r̶o̶w̶s̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶u̶m̶n̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶h̶i̶g̶h̶e̶s̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶s̶m̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶f̶i̶x̶e̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶I̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶(̶e̶)̶`̶ ̶a̶f̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶`̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶`̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶s̶u̶p̶p̶o̶s̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶.̶

See update 2 below.

## Code:

### input:

```
<input type="number" id="myPrice" placeholder="Enter amount.." title="Type in a amount" min="0">
```

### Jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myPrice").on("keyup", function() { //new input
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      $("#myTable tr").show();
      return;
    }
    priceLow = $(this).val() * 0.9; // - 10%
    priceHigh = $(this).val() * 1.1; // + 10%
    $("#myTable tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function(e) {
      var value = parseFloat(this.textContent.replace('$', '')); //convert price to float
      if (value >= priceLow && value <= priceHigh) { //check if in range
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('discarded').show(); //show
      } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('discarded').hide(); //hide
      }
    })
    $("#myTable tr:not(.discarded)").each(function(e) {
      var mark = parseFloat($(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text());
      var price = parseFloat($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text().replace('$', ''));
      var value = parseFloat($(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").text()); 
      if (value > bestrange) {
        bestrangeprice = price;
        bestrangemark = mark;
      }
    });
    $("#myTable tr").each(function(e) {
      var mark = parseFloat($(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text());
      var price = parseFloat($(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").text().replace('$', ''));
      if (price <= bestrangeprice && mark > bestrangemark) { //check if beat bestrange
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('discarded').show(); //show row
    })
  });
});
```

### JS fiddle (with table data):

https://jsfiddle.net/nx30zqjd/17/

## Update:

I've added a bit to fetch the value from non hidden rows to find `bestrange` however im not sure how to compare each row to find the "best".

## Update 2:

I think i have all the code needed now however it doesn't seem to work an example can seen above in the fiddle.

## Other

I can't figure out the last little bits to get it to all work any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I've seen your code in the fiddle and corrected. I think it is working well.

Comment: Did you update the fiddle if so click save and paste the url please

Comment: @AlisherNasrullayev what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your js code was missing some braces and you were calling "onkeyup="myPriceFunction()" which was not defined. I have updated the fiddle and its seems to be working fine.

```
<input type="number" id="myPrice" onkeyup="myPriceFunction()" placeholder="Enter amount.." title="Type in a amount" min="0">
```

The above onkeyup is not required when you have bind the event from js

```
$("#myPrice").on("keyup", function() { 

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nx30zqjd/30/

Comment: I just figured it out there was a lot wrong but i will post an answer here in a while

Answer (score 0):

There were several logical and formatting problems.

All solutions can be found in the [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/nx30zqjd/31/).